# Launch embedded YouTube videos in Quicktime on iOS

Tags: html, ios, safari, youtube, quicktime

We have a requirement to embed videos on a website aimed for Children and would prefer to use a video hosting service.

The likes of YouTube allows for an embedded player to be stripped of chrome and, importantly, the recommended videos displayed after a video ends.

This is important to protect a child from browsing unsuitable content after they have watched the video.

However when viewing a video in iOS, the native YouTube player is launched which has no such child-safe measures.

1. Can the native YouTube app be overridden and the Quicktime player launched instead?
2. Is there another video hosting service that provides child-safe hosting?
3. If we're looking at a self-hosted solution, are there any recommended cross-browser players that take iOS and Android native players into account?

Remember the key requirements are:

- Allow a child to view a video embedded in a web site;
- Protect a child from accessing unsuitable video content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video sharing sites that are completely child-safe are rare but check out 'KidsTube'. It's being actively monitored.

You could also use a HTML5 fallback for mobile safari, it will use the default HTML5 mediaplayer in mobile safari. [As demonstrated by Ben Barnett.](http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/11/24/skinning-the-youtube-player-with-html5-video-support/)

There might be standalone HTML5 mediaplayers that supports YouTube. YouTube itself has it's own instructions to embed HTML5 videos, but i'm not sure if mobile safari is supported ([Info](http://youtube.com/html5)).